# Incorrect Data Getting Written To CSV In R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, data.table

I am writing below `data` to `csv` using `write.csv`, however when I look at the `csv` file then the data in the file is different/more than what I get when I `print()` the `data` to `R` console.

Any suggestions why this is the case?

**Input Data: data**

```
data <- structure(
  list(
    `A` = c(
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_
    ),
    `B` = c("-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5"),
    `T` = c(
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_
    ),
    `C` = c(
      "4.5999999999999996",
      "4.5999999999999996",
      "4.5999999999999996",
      "4.5999999999999996",
      "2.4"
    ),
    `R` = c("V",
            "V", "V", "V", "V"),
    `D` = c(
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_
    ),
    `S` = c(
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_
    ),
    `E` = c(
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_,
      NA_character_
    ),
    `F` = c("Yes",
            "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
    `G` = c("AA",
            "BB", "CC", "DD",
            "EE"),
    `H` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
            NA_real_, NA_real_),
    `I` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
            NA_real_, NA_real_),
    `J` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
            NA_real_, NA_real_),
    `K` = structure(
      c(
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_
      ),
      .Dim = c(5L, 1L)
    ),
    `L` = structure(
      c(
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_
      ),
      .Dim = c(5L, 1L)
    ),
    `M` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,
            NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
    `N` = structure(
      c(
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_
      ),
      .Dim = c(5L, 1L)
    ),
    `O` = structure(list(
      KK = c(NA_real_,
             NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)
    ), row.names = c(NA,
                     5L), class = "data.frame"),
    `P` = structure(list(
      JJ = c(NA_real_,
              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)
    ), row.names = c(NA,
                     5L), class = "data.frame")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 5L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

**write.csv() On Above Data**

```
write.csv(data, file = "data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

**Incorrect Output of Above Code**

```
A   B   T   C   R   D   S   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P                               
NA  -0.5    NA  4.6 V   NA  NA  NA  Yes AA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)    c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)
NA  -0.5    NA  4.6 V   NA  NA  NA  Yes BB  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)    c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)
NA  -0.5    NA  4.6 V   NA  NA  NA  Yes CC  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)    c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)
NA  -0.5    NA  4.6 V   NA  NA  NA  Yes DD  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)    c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)
NA  -0.5    NA  2.4 V   NA  NA  NA  Yes EE  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)    c(NA     NA  NA  NA  NA)
```

**Desired Output of print()**

```
> print(data)
     A    B    T                  C R    D    S    E   F  G  H  I  J    K    L  M    N KK JJ
1 <NA> -0.5 <NA> 4.5999999999999996 V <NA> <NA> <NA> Yes AA NA NA NA <NA> <NA> NA <NA> NA NA
2 <NA> -0.5 <NA> 4.5999999999999996 V <NA> <NA> <NA> Yes BB NA NA NA <NA> <NA> NA <NA> NA NA
3 <NA> -0.5 <NA> 4.5999999999999996 V <NA> <NA> <NA> Yes CC NA NA NA <NA> <NA> NA <NA> NA NA
4 <NA> -0.5 <NA> 4.5999999999999996 V <NA> <NA> <NA> Yes DD NA NA NA <NA> <NA> NA <NA> NA NA
5 <NA> -0.5 <NA>                2.4 V <NA> <NA> <NA> Yes EE NA NA NA <NA> <NA> NA <NA> NA NA
```

I am not concerned about numerical values, but more about why the last few columns are different than what I see in console using print().

Comment: Seems like your differentiation between `4.6` and `4.599999...` is related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). But since it's happening during you writing to a file, it might be impacted by `write.csv`'s comment: *"In almost all cases the conversion of numeric quantities is governed by the option '"scipen"' (see 'options'), but with the internal equivalent of 'digits = 15'.  For finer control, use 'format' to make a character matrix/data frame, and call 'write.table' on that."*.

Comment: You've got mixed types in the data frame. The last two columns are data frames themselves. The lines are being written out to the CSV file with `c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)` in the final two columns, because the `write.csv` doesn't know what to do with the data frames. Use `save` to save the structure and retrieve it (correctly) with `load`.

Comment: @r2evans - I did add in question that I am not concerned about that. I am more interested in the extra columns and how different the data is compare to the `print(data)`.

Comment: @EdwardCarney - I tried `save(data, file = "data.RData")` and then cleaned up the work space using `rm(list=ls())`. Then loaded using `load("data.RData")`, but this didn't help. Writing to file after these operation still leads to same data issue. Can you please elaborate what I should do correctly?

Comment: These suggestions may or may not help: Create an R object (data.table) first before using fwrite or write.csv.  I then use 'sapply(DT,class)'  or sapply(DF,class)'  to check the datatypes.  Rdata.table will import lists as list objects which I have found problematic. Last, I use setnames() to rename any columns labeled with "T" or "F".  I have found columns labeled "T" and "F" to be problematic. I believe I see problems with your "T" and "F" columns above.  Also test for differences between fwrite/write.csv and fread/read.delim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is nested. In this case, it is trivial and obvious in its immediate remedy, but if your data is not perfectly cooperative in reality then this answer may not suffice.

Here's a cause: embedded frames in the last two columns:

```r
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  19 variables:
#  $ A: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ B: chr  "-0.5" "-0.5" "-0.5" "-0.5" ...
#  $ T: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ C: chr  "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" ...
#  $ R: chr  "V" "V" "V" "V" ...
#  $ D: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ S: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ E: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ F: chr  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" ...
#  $ G: chr  "AA" "BB" "CC" "DD" ...
#  $ H: num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ I: num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ J: num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ K: chr [1:5, 1] NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ L: chr [1:5, 1] NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ M: num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ N: chr [1:5, 1] NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ O:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:       <-----
#   ..$ KK: num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ P:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:       <-----
#   ..$ JJ: num  NA NA NA NA NA
```

Let's verify that our "simple" fix is safe enough:

```r
islst <- sapply(dat, is.list)
# ASSERT: number of rows and embedded lists/frames are the same length
all(nrow(dat) == sapply(dat[islst], lengths))
# [1] TRUE
```

That's important, as the following will either fail (better) or functionally succeed but logically disrupt the data with no warning (bad!).

```r
dat <- do.call("cbind.data.frame", c(dat[!islst], dat[islst], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  19 variables:
#  $ A : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ B : chr  "-0.5" "-0.5" "-0.5" "-0.5" ...
#  $ T : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ C : chr  "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" ...
#  $ R : chr  "V" "V" "V" "V" ...
#  $ D : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ S : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ E : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ F : chr  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" ...
#  $ G : chr  "AA" "BB" "CC" "DD" ...
#  $ H : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ I : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ J : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ K : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ L : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ M : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ N : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ KK: num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ JJ: num  NA NA NA NA NA
```

From here you can use `write.csv` and write a correct CSV file.

Note that you have lost the `P` column name here, replaced by `KK` and `JJ` (the nested column names). If preserving the `P` name is important, then do this instead (using the original `dat` unmodified):

```r
dat[islst] <- Map(function(x, onm, inm) `names<-`(x, paste(onm, inm, sep = ".")),
                  dat[islst], names(dat[islst]), sapply(dat[islst], names))
dat <- do.call("cbind.data.frame", c(dat[!islst], dat[islst], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  19 variables:
#  $ A   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ B   : chr  "-0.5" "-0.5" "-0.5" "-0.5" ...
#  $ T   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ C   : chr  "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" "4.5999999999999996" ...
#  $ R   : chr  "V" "V" "V" "V" ...
#  $ D   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ S   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ E   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ F   : chr  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" ...
#  $ G   : chr  "AA" "BB" "CC" "DD" ...
#  $ H   : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ I   : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ J   : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ K   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ L   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ M   : num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ N   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ O.KK: num  NA NA NA NA NA
#  $ P.JJ: num  NA NA NA NA NA
```

BTW: there are certainly other options here that win by code-golf:

```r
dat$P <- dat$P$JJ
dat$O <- dat$O$KK
```

but if you have variable numbers of columns within `O` and `P`, it becomes a manual process. The solution I offered above is more programmatic and dynamic.

---

Side note: I renamed the variable for use here as `dat`, as `data` (and many other variable names) is the name of a base R function; troubleshooting is complicated (especially if you don't know what a "closure" is) when variables are named like this, namely when you forget to load all of them and expect things to work. As an example, which error is clearer to you?

```r
# oops, I did not load my 'data' frame
summary(data)
# Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

# oops, I did not load my 'x' frame
summary(x)
# Error in summary(x) : object 'x' not found
```

Comment: Does this answer solve your question? If not, can you say what doesn't work? (If so, please accept it.)